# struct with pointer to arr of different sizes

Tags: c, embedded

Learning ANSI  C. (Embedded so malloc is out). Can't get my head around how I can have N buffers with diffent buffersizes, (sharing the same struct), at least not without compiler warnings:

```
typedef struct Ringbuffer {
  uint8_t wrIdx;
  uint8_t lag;
  //obvious, but with fixed size:
  char buffer[32];
  //what I'd like
  uint8_t buffLength;
  char *buffer;
} Ringbuffer;

//By concept...
Ringbuffer myRBs[3];
char rs485out[64];
char rs485in[16];
myRBs[0].buffLength=64;
myRBs[0].buffer = &rs485out;
myRBs[1].buffLength=16;
myRBs[1].buffer = &rs485in;
```

Debugging, the code seems to be working, but i get GCC-compiler warning:

```
# warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type at ( .. = &rs485out)
```

Am I doing it wrong here? Is the warning fixable?

Comment: You would do better to to assign the buffer lengths thus: `myRBs[0].buffLength = sizeof(rs485out) ;`.  Embedded == no malloc is not a given - it depends entirely on the platform and the application requirements; it just requires more care and an understanding of the possible consequences.

Comment: Hi Clifford, you're right. There is DO-178B however. CU at avrfreaks, ;-)

Comment: DO-178B compliance would be one of the *application requirements* I spoke of, so I guess I covered that?  Moreover DO-178B would presumably also preclude the magic numbers in your code in any case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `&`. When an array is used as an rvalue, it becomes a pointer to its first element. So do:

```
myRBs[0].buffer = rs485out;
```

Comment: Also if you're worried about doing something "bad" in an embedded environment, you're not.  Your method here of assigning fixed size buffers to pointers is exactly the idea in embedded environments.